# In angular2 How to assign id value to url

Tags: angular2-services

Here i  wrote angular2 url part as

```
  onselect(StateId: Country) {
        var GetstateValue = this.http.post("http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById/",+StateId)
 GetstateValue.subscribe(res => this.Success)
```

But its not Binding StateId value (Here id value is comming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Angular GET and POST

get method:

```html
 onselect(StateId: Country) {
        var GetstateValue = this.http.get("http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById/"+StateId)
 GetstateValue.subscribe(res =>{ this.Success=res; console.log(res);)
```

post method

```html
 onselect(StateId: Country) {
  const header = new Headers();
      header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      let data = StateId;
        var GetstateValue = this.http.post("http://localhost:34339/Home/GetStateById/", data, {headers: header}).map(res=>res.json());
 GetstateValue.subscribe(res => this.Success);
```

Comment: Here what is   const header = new Headers();  I know    import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from "@angular/http"...But I dont wat type of Headers u had taken

Comment: post method should have header, without header post method shouldn't occur. See my [github](https://github.com/thangavel28/studentlogin) under app->service->service.ts

Comment: may i know ur Contact num Beacause im new 2 Ang2 I hv lot of doubut If u help me small its Good For me